# How to type and display different languages in Parrot Security OS?

Tags: language, parrotsec

I've tried downloading the SCIM input method program. Normally I should be able to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch languages, however, this hot-key is not working. How to enable Korean language typing and also to be able to display it in the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by "be able to display it in the terminal"? The default language being Korean?

Answer (score 0):

## Modifying keymaps

### Method 1

You can setup keymaps, both for X11 and terminal, by modifying the file `etc/default/keyboard`.

If you want to setup English and Korean, and switching between both with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, you need to edit the following lines:

```
 XKBLAYOUT="us,ko"
 XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

### Method 2

You can use `setxkbmap` to define different keymaps and how to switch between them, such as following:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout us,ko -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

The command line above sets two differents keymaps `en_US` and `ko_KO` and enables to change between both with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.